# Finding distribution of parameter for exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, exponential-distribution, maximum-likelihood, confidence-interval, parameter-estimation

I came across this question:

> Given a sample of 50 values all coming from an exponential distribution where $f(x)=\theta x^{-x/\theta}$, find the MLE for theta. Then, find the 95% confidence interval for $\theta$.

My question is can I assume theta is normally distributed as n>30 so the CLT applies and then how do I find the expected value and variance of theta to then get the standard error of the interval

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. What is the definition of MLE?

Comment: Your PDF has a typo. Do you want it to read $\theta e^{-\theta x}$ or $\tfrac{1}{\theta}e^{-x/\theta}$?

Comment: The MLE here refers to maximum likelihood estimator

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are dealing with the following density

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}$$

with mean $\mu=\theta$ and variance $\sigma^2=\theta^2$, $x\geq 0$

...easy find that $\hat{\theta}_{ML}=\overline{X}_{50}$ and remembering that the sample mean has the following asympthotic distribution

$$\overline{X}_{50}\dot{\sim} N(\theta;\frac{\theta^2}{50})$$

Thus to find you 95% approx CI you have only to solve in $\theta$ the following double inequality

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]
{
-1.96<\frac{\overline{X}_{50}-\theta}{\overline{X}_{50}}\sqrt{50}<1.96
\qquad   (1)
}
$$

... having estimated Sample mean's Standard deviation with $\frac{\overline{X}_{50}}{\sqrt{50}}$

---

On the contrary, if you are dealing with $f_X(x)=\theta e^{-\theta x}$ follow the same brainstorming modifying the forumlas I showed, accordingly

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]
{
-1.96<\frac{\overline{X}_{50}-\frac{1}{\theta}}{\overline{X}_{50}}\sqrt{50}<1.96
\qquad   (2)
}
$$

---

**Personal opinion**: even if the sample is large enough, I think it is easier to find the exact Confidence interval, using the $\chi^2$ distribution instead of having a Gaussian approx

Comment: I appreciate it. The part I’m hung up on is that the MLE is 1/(\bar{x}) and I’m confused how to get the expected value and variance of that estimator with the sum of x_i in the denominator. Would you be able to write that out? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ChrisB : MLE = $\frac{1}{\overline{X}}$ is for the following density $f=\theta e^{-\theta x}$. To derive mean and variance of this estimator you have to use Gamma Function or, better, inverse gamma function. This is not necessary because $\overline{X}$ is the sufficient estimator so my answer is good in any case...modifying the formulas accordingly to the parametrized density

Comment: @ChrisB : first clarify which parametrization of exponential density you are requested to use...me and J.G. already asked you to clarify...

Comment: thank you! I appreciate it!

Comment: I would like to use the second parametrization you presented

Comment: @Chris B : $\frac{1}{\theta}$ is monotone function of $\theta$ thus the extremes of the CI are the reciprocal of the ones I showed before (reversed, of course)

Comment: thanks so much!